# How to create new theme in drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Can anyone please help me in creating a new theme using drupal 7?
I wanted to know the steps to create it. If there is any documentation for creating new themes then it would be great. 
It would be great if anyone says what is need to write in the files .info, *.tpl.php, .css and .js.

Comment: I would start trying on drupal6 this is much more stable and has more documentation. Then you can try upgrading your theme.

Comment: http://learnwebscripts.com/how-to-create-a-simple-basic-drupal-7-theme-from-scratch
check out this site it helps to know how to create a theme in durpal 7 from scratch it will be very useful for the Beginners

Answer (score 9):

If you are after a simple tutorial on creating Drupal themes, try this one:

- [How to Make a Drupal Theme](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-theme)

This covers version 6, which is the current release of Drupal.  I couldn't find anything specific to the upcoming Drupal 7 release, but if you need detailed information on the changes between and 7, try these:

- [Converting 6.x themes to 7.x](http://drupal.org/update/theme/6/7)
- [Drupal 7 theme changes](http://pingv.com/blog/al-steffen/2009/drupal-7-theme-changes)

Comment: Upvoted as this is really the only information available, but it does not answer the question. The link misleadingly titled "How to Make a Drupal Theme" shows how to modify one theme to appear differently. It does not address the "Hello, world" aspect of creating a Drupal theme.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're really best off by looking at a basic starter theme and going from there. The "Basic" theme is a really good one (http://drupal.org/project/basic) and has a stable D7 release.

Quite a few things have changed, such as the use of html.tpl.php so that you can have multiple page.tpl.php's without having to duplicate the .

EDIT: Why are you creating a theme for D7? Hopefully it's just for practice and not for a real site that will be launching anytime soon?

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7 I found this site is helpful in getting everything set up correctly:

http://www.lifeisaprayer.com/articles/web-design/building-a-theme-drupal-7

The link below has the variables used in Drupal 7.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

This video gives a good starter on how to creat a drupal 7 theme and she has follow up videos that explains more. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCg4sTA3DlQ

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7, the core Bartik is an excellent theme and easy to customize. Read more about customizing Bartik here: http://drupal.org/node/1114190

Answer (score 1):

You could also go for the [Zen theme](http://www.drupal.org/project/zen). It's well-documented, frequently updated, and it has a lot of features. Furthermore, I ran into trouble when I just copied over the Bartik theme.

To work with the Zen theme, you have to figure out how to create a subtheme, but it's well worth figuring out. It's also described step by step on the Zen project pages. There's even a module that sets up subthemes for you called zenophile.

Answer (score 1):

The official [**theming guide**](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) is very explanatory. If you are writing a theme from scratch I suggest this is the way to go. Among other things, it contains the 20 minutes [***Introduction to Theming Basics for Drupal 7***](http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7) video.